# Acceder a enlaces creados en un <textarea>

Tags: python, django, regex

A partir de un texto creado en un `<textarea>`, necesito poder acceder a aquellos enlaces que se hayan introducido.

Por ejemplo, introduzco:

> Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. https://www.stackoverflow.com Beatae eum nobis distinctio sapiente maxime ex dolorum, fuga voluptas architecto
>
> https://www.stackoverflow.com
>
> https://www.stackoverflow.com
>
> asperiores voluptatibus cupiditate sequi incidunt aperiam. https://www.stackoverflow.com 
>   Repellat recusandae quas eos error?

(El editor de Stackoverflow ya los detecta automáticamente, pero imaginemos que es texto plano)

Como podría, a partir del texto plano, cambiar el enlace del texto y convertirlo en una etiqueta `<a>` para mostrarlo en un template de Django?

He pensado que quizá se podría buscar en el texto el enlace con un **regex** y reemplazarlo, pero no se cómo hacerlo. Eso sí, el regex que he probado y que funciona es

```
regex = r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En principio puedes usar [django.utils.html.urlize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) o  [django.utils.html.urlizetrunc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlizetrunc)  para esto en vez de recurrir a implementarlo por ti mismo vía regex:

```
text = """Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur
adipisicing elit. https://www.stackoverflow.com
Beatae eum nobis distinctio sapiente maxime ex dolorum,
fuga voluptas architecto https://ru.stackoverflow.com
https://es.stackoverflow.com asperiores
voluptatibus cupiditate sequi incidunt aperiam.
https://pt.stackoverflow.com Repellat recusandae
quas eos error?
"""


from django.utils.html import urlize
print(urlize(text))
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur
adipisicing elit. <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">https://www.stackoverflow.com</a>
Beatae eum nobis distinctio sapiente maxime ex dolorum,
fuga voluptas architecto <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com">https://ru.stackoverflow.com</a>
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">https://es.stackoverflow.com</a> asperiores
voluptatibus cupiditate sequi incidunt aperiam.
<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com">https://pt.stackoverflow.com</a> Repellat recusandae
quas eos error?
```

Para implementar algo así con regex , puedes hacer uso de `re.sub` englobando tu expresión en un grupo y a partir de ahí construir la etiqueta. Por ejemplo, usando la expresión que tu mismo proporcionas:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+)')
urlize_text = re.sub(regex, r'<a href="\1">\1</a>', text)
```

---

### Extra

Si solo queremos extraer los links obviando el resto del texto, se puede usar `re.finditer`:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(http[s]?://((?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+))')
urls = [match.expand(r'<a href="\1">\1</a>') for match in re.finditer(regex, text)]
print(urls)
```

> ```
> ['<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">https://www.stackoverflow.com</a>',
>  '<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com">https://ru.stackoverflow.com</a>',
>  '<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">https://es.stackoverflow.com</a>',
>  '<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com">https://pt.stackoverflow.com</a>'
> ]
> ```